# Using variable to delete node in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, nodes

I am rather new with XSLT.

I was trying to remove a node from my XML based on a value of another node in the XML.

let's say I have this XML:

```
    <root>
    <body>
        <order>
            <orderAttributes>
                <attributeID>1</attributeID>
                <attributeValue>AAA</attributeValue>               
            </orderAttributes>
            <orderAttributes>
                <attributeID>2</attributeID>
                <attributeValue>BBB</attributeValue>                               
            </orderAttributes>            
        </order>
        <order>
            <orderAttributes>
                <attributeID>3</attributeID>
                <attributeValue>CCC</attributeValue>               
            </orderAttributes>
            <orderAttributes>                
                <attributeID>4</attributeID>
                <attributeValue>DDD</attributeValue>               
            </orderAttributes>          
        </order>
        <order>
            <orderAttributes>               
                <attributeID>5</attributeID>
                <attributeValue>EEE</attributeValue>               
            </orderAttributes>
            <orderAttributes>                
                <attributeID>6</attributeID>
                <attributeValue>FFF</attributeValue>               
            </orderAttributes>           
        </order>
    </body>
</root>
```

and I have the following XSLT (ver 1.0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:param name="Attribute2" select="'BBB'" />
    <xsl:param name="Attribute3" select="'TTT'" />

    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="orderAttributes">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="attributeID[text()=3]">
                <attributeValueChangeX9>
                    <attributeID>3</attributeID>
                    <attributeValue><xsl:value-of select="$Attribute3"/></attributeValue>
                </attributeValueChangeX9>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="order//orderAttributes[attributeID='6']">
    </xsl:template>
```

This will change the value of attributeID 3 to "TTT" and remove attributeID 6.

However, if I want to base the deletion of attribute 6 on the value of attribute 3 I would add something like this:

```
    <xsl:template match="order//orderAttributes[attributeID='6'][preceding::orderAttributes[attributeIDX9='3' and valueX9='TTT']]">
```

Of course this will not work as the XSLT is not procedural and will only work on the source tree. 
trying to use the parameter as a condition cannot be done either, as I cannot use variables in a match pattern.

is there any way I can do something like this?
(for the purpose of the example I gave the default value of attribute3 as 'TTT', but this is an input parameter that may be changed by whoever uses this XSLT)

Comment: "*I want to base the deletion of attribute 6 on the value of attribute 3*" What exactly does that mean? You want to delete attribute 6  when the value of attribute 3 is ... what?

Comment: like I show in my example - when the value is TTT. However TTT is only happening in the XSLT

Comment: In your example, the value of attribute 3 is "CCC". Please formulate the condition based on the input (including, if necessary, the parameters), and not on the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, you are trying to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="Attribute2" select="'BBB'" />
<xsl:param name="Attribute3" select="'TTT'" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="orderAttributes[attributeID='3']">
    <attributeValueChangeX9>
        <attributeID>3</attributeID>
        <attributeValue>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Attribute3"/>
        </attributeValue>
    </attributeValueChangeX9>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="orderAttributes[attributeID='6']"> 
    <xsl:if test="$Attribute3 != 'TTT'">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the `Attribute2` parameter is not used anywhere.